# Android, hook mount as flash drive

Tags: android, mount, usb-drive

There are way for:
On USB connect to PC (or other flash drive reader) - hook process and allow access only specified files and folder on android (custom store)?

Answer (score 0):

Only by creating your own firmware.

SDK applications cannot interfere with either the USB Mass Storage mode or the USB Media Transfer Protocol forms of mounting Android external storage as drives on a host computer.